# Hide element from showing up in the Dom using react and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have been working with a react and firebasea app createing a to do list project where I add update delete items from an array but when nothing is added there is a 0 being showed inside the Dom. how do I not show this 0 then show when I add a to do item using my add to list button on submit. I'm using map and have tried to slice the array but that doesn't work any ideas?

```
       export default class Profile extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
     user: getAuth().currentUser,
     notes: [],
     content: "",
     note: {},
     name: "",
     location: "",
     date: new Date(),
     list: [],
   };

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.submitData = this.submitData.bind(this);
   this.updateDoc = this.updateDoc.bind(this);
   this.DeleteDoc = this.DeleteDoc.bind(this);
   this.getList = this.getList.bind(this);
 }

 handleChange(e) {
   const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
   console.log("name, value +++", name, value);
   if (name === "name") {
     this.setState({ name: value });
   } else if (name === "location") {
     this.setState({ location: value });
   }
   //  else if (name === "date") {
   //   this.setState({ date: value });
   // }
   console.log("========", e);
 }

 async submitData(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   await firestore
     .collection("user")
     .add({
       name: this.state.name,
       location: this.state.location,
       date: this.state.date,
     })
     .then((docRef) => {
       console.log("data added +++", docRef);
     })
     .catch((e) => console.log("add error", e));
   this.getList();
 }
 handleDateChange(date) {
   console.log(date);
   this.setState({ date: date });
 }

 updateDoc(e, id) {
   e.preventDefault();
   firestore.doc(`user/${id}`).update({
     name: this.state.name,
     location: this.state.location,
     date: this.state.date,
   });
   this.getList();
 }
 DeleteDoc(e, id) {
   e.preventDefault();
   firestore.doc(`user/${id}`).delete({
     name: this.state.name,
     location: this.state.location,
     date: this.state.date,
   });
   this.getList();
 }

 getOnlyDate(dateVal) {
   let res = dateVal;
   console.log("=========", dateVal);
   let tempArr = dateVal.split(",");
   if (tempArr.length > 1) {
     res = tempArr[0];
   }

   return res;
 }

 getList() {
   let list = [];

   let today = new Date();

   let tomorrow = new Date();
   tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
   let todayStart = today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
   // let todayd = todayStart.toLocaleString();
   let tomorrowStart = tomorrow.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

   firestore
     .collection("user")
     .get()
     .then((snapshot) => {
       console.log("snapshot +++", snapshot);
       snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
         console.log("user data doc +++", doc.id, doc.data());

         let data = doc.data();
         let data_id = doc.id;

         console.log(data.date.seconds);
         let dataDate = new Date(data.date.seconds * 1000);
         let fireStoreDate = dataDate.getTime();
         console.log(dataDate.toLocaleString());
         if (fireStoreDate >= todayStart && fireStoreDate < tomorrowStart) {
           list.push({
             id: data_id,
             name: data.name,
             location: data.location,
             date: this.getOnlyDate(dataDate.toLocaleString()),
           });
         }
       });

       console.log("result of list");
       console.log(list);

       this.setState({
         notes: [...list],
       });
     });
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.getList();
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="todo-list  ">
       <Header></Header>

       <div>
         Login in as: <strong>{this.state.user.email}</strong>
       </div>
       <div className="row">
         <input
           required
           type="text"
           name="name"
           id="name"
           placeholder="add a todo "
           onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
         />
         <input
           required
           type="text"
           name="location"
           id="location"
           placeholder="add location "
           onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
         />
         <DatePicker
           selected={this.state.date}
           onChange={(date) => this.handleDateChange(date)}
         ></DatePicker>
       </div>
       <div className="row">
         <button
           className="btn btn-success"
           type="button"
           onClick={(e) => this.submitData(e)}
         >
           Add to list
         </button>
       </div>
       <div className="row ">
         {this.state.notes.length &&
           this.state.notes.map((user) => {
             return (
               <div class="card todo-list color" key= 
            {this.state.notes.id}>
                 <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title"> To Do Item</h5>

                   <input type="checkbox" className="" />
                   <p class="card-text">To Do: {user?.name}</p>

                   <p class="card-text">Location: {user?.location}</p>

                   <p class="card-text">Date:{user?.date}</p>
                 </div>

                 <div d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end>
                   <button
                     type="button"
                 className="  justify-content-center btn-primary me-md-2"
                     onClick={(e) => this.updateDoc(e, user.id)}
                   >
                     Update
                   </button>
                   <button
                     justify-content-center
                     type="button"
                     className=" btn-danger "
                     onClick={(e) => this.DeleteDoc(e, user.id)}
                   >
                     Delete
                   </button>
                 </div>
               </div>
             );
           })}
       </div>
       <Footer></Footer>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: see full project here on guthub https://github.com/JohnSolomou/capstone-3-todo-app

Answer (score 0):

under `<div className="row ">` delete this line
`this.state.notes.length &&`